# Is it wise to always return in functions?

Tags: javascript

I read somewhere a while back (unfortunately can't remember where), that it was wise to always put a `return` statement at the end of every function in JavaScript, because it clears the memory of objects and variables created in that function.

Is there any truth to that?

Comment: Functions always return, whether or not you use a `return` statement. Adding a `return` statement will do nothing to clear memory or variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no truth in that. None.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everybody. I didn't think there was any truth to that claim but I had been thinking about it today and couldn't find anything online. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

No.

From [Standard ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)  (12.9):

> **Syntax**
>
> *ReturnStatement*:
>   `return ;`
>   `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression* `;`
>
> [...] A `return` statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the 
>   caller. If `Expression` is omitted, the return value is `undefined`. Otherwise, the return value is the value of *Expression*.

The opposite is true, however: a `return` statement can prevent memory from being freed.

From [Functions and function scope - MDN # Preservation of variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Preservation_of_variables):

```
function outside(x) {
   function inside(y) {
      return x + y;
   }
   return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3); 
result = fn_inside(5); // returns 8

result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```

> Notice how `x` is preserved when `inside` is returned. A closure must preserve the arguments and variables in all scopes it references. Since each call provides potentially different arguments, a new closure is created for each call to `outside`. The memory can be freed only when the returned `inside` is no longer accessible.